# How find given number is octal or not?

Tags: java

In this I find octal number upto 3 digits and i use lengthy if conditions can anyone lessen this if statement and values assigned. Note that don't use prdefined process or inbuilt packages..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class octdec
{
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    int back=0;
    do
        {
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no,mod1,mod2,mod3,diff1,diff2,diff3,num1,num2,num3;
        System.out.print("Enter Octal No upto 3 digits : ");
        no=ip.nextInt();
        mod1=no%10;
        mod2=no%100;
        mod3=no%1000;
        diff1=no-mod1;
        diff2=no-mod2;
        diff3=no-mod3;
        num1=diff1/10;
        num2=diff2/100;
        num3=diff3/1000;
        if(no==8||no==9||mod1==8||mod1==9||mod2==8||mod2==9||mod3==8||mod3==9||num1==8||num1==9||num2==8||num2==9||num3==8||num3==9)
        System.out.println("Invaild Octal Nimber ");
        else
        System.out.println("Vaild Octal Nimber :"+no);
        }
    while(back==0);
    }
}
```

Comment: HINT: Use `while` loop.

Comment: An `int` doesn't have a property that it is octal, decimal or whatever. Octal, decimal, hexadecimal etc. are just different ways to display a number - it's not an intrinsic property of the number. You cannot take an `int` and check if it is octal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regex to match only octal numbers:

```
  ^0[1-7][0-7]*$
```

- ^,$: Anchors
- 0: A literal 0. All octal numbers begin with a 0.
- [1-7]: Char class for digits from 1 to 7 as only these are valid octal digits.
- *: Quantifier for zero or more of the previous thing.

So basically this regex matches only those strings that have a 0 in the beginning and contain one or more digits from 1 to 7.

If the leading 0 requirement is not there you can use the regex:

```
^[1-7][0-7]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the number passing the radix like below

```
    try{
         String number="30";
         int i=Integer.parseInt(number,8); // returns the integer represented by the  string argument in the specified radix.

         System.out.println("Octal Number");
       }  catch(NumberFormatException e)  {
           System.out.println("Not an octal number");
       }
```

If the given number is not octal, It thrown `NumberFormatException.`

Here 8 is radix or base - representing octal number

Answer (score 1):

try `ip.nextInt(8)`.
This will ensure input value must be in octal but `return` the decimal value of the input octal value

Answer (score 1):

Yet another utility:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IsOctal_Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number : \n");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("isOctal : "+isOctal(input));
    }

    public static boolean isOctal(String octal) {
        boolean isOctal = false;
        if (octal != null && !octal.isEmpty()) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(octal);
            while (number > 0) {
                if (number % 10 <= 7) {
                    isOctal = true;
                } else {
                    isOctal = false;
                    break;
                }
                number /= 10;
            }
        }
        return isOctal;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/java-programs/octal-number-checking-java-program.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should read it as a decimal integer and then try to figure out if it might be octal (so you read it wrong and have to convert it). You better read it as string and then check or try to parse it as octal.

@gowtham told you how to convert and @murtaza.webdev told you how to check as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Method

```
/**
 * 
 * @param octalInput
 * @return boolean flag that determines value input by user is a valid octal number  
 */
   public static boolean isValidOctalInput( String octalInput )
    {

         return octalInput.matches( "[0-7]*$" );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ but here goes:

```cpp
static constexpr std::string_view prefixes[] = { "0o", "0", "o", "q" };
std::string_view val("q777");
size_t index = 0;

for (const auto prefix : prefixes) {
    if (val.rfind(prefix, 0) == 0) {
        index = prefix.length();
        break;
    }
}

bool isOctal = index == 0 || val.length() <= index ? false : 
std::count_if(val.begin() + index, val.end(), [](const char c) {
    return isdigit(c) && c <= '7';
}) == val.length() - index;
```